# get the continuous value of week number for the next following year

Tags: r

Can someone help me,
How to get the continuous value of week number for the next following year.
For example 50,51,52,53,54,55,56 ...

Here's my code below:

```
now <- as.Date(Sys.time())
dates <- seq(now, now + 900, by = "1 day") 
dat <- data.frame(Dates = dates, Week = format(dates, format = "%W"))
dat
```

I want the value continuing to 54,55,56,... instead of starting over from 0,1,2,.. on year change
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
round(difftime(dates, now, units = "weeks"))

# Time differences in weeks
#  [1]   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

Dates <- seq(today(), today() + 900, by = "days")
Week  <- week(Dates)
dat   <- data.frame(Dates, Week)

dat %>% 
  mutate(
    cumsum = as.integer(cumsum(c(0, diff(Week) != 0))),
    Week_new = case_when(
      year(Dates) %in% year("2017-01-01") ~ Week,
      TRUE                                ~ week(min(Dates)) + cumsum
  )
)
```

giving you

```
#        Dates Week cumsum Week_new
#.. ..........   ..      .       ..
#45 2017-12-29   52      6       52
#46 2017-12-30   53      7       53
#47 2017-12-31   53      7       53
#48 2018-01-01    1      8       54
#49 2018-01-02    1      8       54
#50 2018-01-03    1      8       54
#.. ..........    .      .       ..
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)